# Python returning a true statement even if false (trying to find if a letter exists in a program)

Tags: python, return

I am very new to coding, and this will probably be a quick answer for most of you. It's a school assignment. Here is my code:

```
def letter(r): 
    """Determines if a string contains an uppercase or lowercase r"""

    if 'r' in '**r**':
        return "There is the letter r somewhere in there!"

    else:
        return "The letter r is not located here!"

r = str(input('Enter a phrase: '))

print(letter(r))
```

The program will run successfully, however it always returns the "if" string regardless of if the letter r is in the phrase.

Example from console:

> > > (executing file "has_r.py")
> > >
> > > Enter a phrase: not
> > >
> > > There is a letter r somewhere in there!

Comment: Because `'r' in '**r**'` is `True`...

Comment: What do you think `'**r**'` is accomplishing?

Comment: That's something to ask the teacher's assistant. I was told to put that there.

Comment: Try actually thinking about the code you're writing and comprehending.

Comment: I'm getting there, Jonathon. I've only started 2 weeks ago and have been trying to teach myself as I go. This site seems to be helping me out a lot so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your if statement to:

```
if 'r' in r:
....
```

The if statement always runs as r is always in 
"**r**"